# Xamarin : Get data from ArrayAdapter after rotating screen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-arrayadapter

When I'm rotating my screen, the data in my ArrayAdapter will disappear. Someone knows how to fix it?

My code in MainActivity.cs

```
private int count = 0;
private IList<string> intervals = new List<string>();
private ArrayAdapter<string> listAdapter;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                this.timeView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.timeView);

                this.interval = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.interval);
                this.listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, intervals);
                this.interval.Adapter = listAdapter;

                RunOnUiThread(() => { listAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();});
                this.timeView.Click += (IntentSender, eventArgs) => addInterval();
            }

private void addInterval() { 
            this.listAdapter.Insert(++this.count + "\t\t\t\t" + string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff}",this.accumulatedTime),0);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotate your screen, your current activity is being torn down. Any item without an `id` will lose it's value.

Hence try using

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
String[] aavalues = aAdapter.getValue(); 
savedState.putStringArray("enter a key value here", aavalues);}
```

You'll have to define a `getValue` method for obtaining the values inside your adapter.

Then since your activity is being destroyed it'll enter `oncreate` again.

Initalise your adapter there

```
    String[] avalues = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("the key value from before");
    if (values != null) {
       aAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(avalues);}
```

Comment: Ok, but my question was how to get my data from my ArrayAdapter, not counter, because you can not store an ArrayAdapter in SharedPreferences, Am I right?

Comment: Consider using also the Application class to store the data and load them on rotate from there